# Puppet does not work with augeas in a multiple ruby versions environment

Tags: puppet, ruby, augeas

I am trying to make puppet work with augeas but it complains there is no augeas provider. Some googling suggested to

```
sudo yum install augeas
augtool ls /files/etc/php.ini # test it works as expected
sudo yum install ruby-augeas # this is to "bridge" ruby and augeas
ruby -raugeas -e "puts Augeas.open" # Test ruby can talk to augeas
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- augeas (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Everything works and installs apart from the last line. Ruby just does not know where to find augeas.rb because it is not in the ruby include path

```
[vagrant@SubscriptionsAPI ~]$ sudo find / -name "augeas.rb"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/puppet-3.4.3/lib/puppet/provider/augeas/augeas.rb
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/puppet-3.4.3/lib/puppet/type/augeas.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/augeas.rb

[vagrant@SubscriptionsAPI ~]$ ruby -e 'puts $:'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linuxе
```

Am I correct assuming this is the case? If yes, how can I install augeas for a specific Ruby version? Or is it cleaner to modify the ruby include path?

Comment: You're mixing up rvm with packages, that is not really a good idea. I suppose you did not install Puppet in RVM, did you?

Comment: btw, it's "Augeas", not "Augeos"

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question. I am using a Vagrant base box from a 3rd party  - https://vagrantcloud.com/ginja/boxes/centos-6.5-x64-rvm-ruby2.0.0-puppet. It says Puppet was installed using gem

Comment: @ℝaphink Thanks! You pointed me to the right direction, I had to install a missing augeas-devel package and then install the provider though gem -gem install ruby-augeas. Works like a charm now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packaged ruby libraries and RVM are two separate environments. You cannot mix them like that, you need to choose which one to use.

So you need to either:

- install the ruby Augeas bindings using packages
- or install Puppet in RVM